# Empty View taken space

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I want to show EmptyView() without space if there is no data from sever.

If I put my code inside VStack then EmptyView() takes the space,
If I put the code without Stack, then API is calling infinite number.

My code is follow:

```
VStack{
    if let arr = vm.arrMessages{
        getContent()
            .padding(.top)
    } else if vm.isLoading {
        ProgressView()
    } else if vm.isError {
        EmptyView()
    }
}

// Outside of VStack:

if let arr = vm.arrMessages{
    getContent()
        .padding(.top)
} else if vm.isLoading {
    ProgressView()
} else if vm.isError {
    EmptyView()
}
```

then API is calling infinite time.

thank you

Comment: The "space" is probably just the `VStack`'s default spacing. `VStack(spacing: 0)` should fix that. But "API is calling infinite time if outside VStack" sounds like there is another problem here, and you should also fix that.

Comment: A snippet of the view model and how it is observed (State/Observed) in the view could help.. also the view hierarchy (who is the parent and how it is being updated) can help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inside the `VStack`, you can simply don't put anything to get rid of undesired spacing:

```
VStack {
    if let arr = vm.arrMessages{
        getContent()
            .padding(.top)
    } else if vm.isLoading {
        ProgressView()
    } else if vm.isError {
        /* Nothing Here */ //  Return nothing
    }
}
```

You can also set a custom spacing like `0` for the Stack like:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) { //  The default value is dynamic value called `standard` which most of the time appears around 8 points
    ,,,
}
```